# European driver's license Type B and 10,000lb vehicle in USA

Tags: usa, driving-licenses

We are a Belgian couple and want to travel in the US with a truck camper. This truck camper will weigh around 10,000 lbs (4500 kg).

In Belgium we have a driver's licence Type B (European and International), the normal driver's licence for a car. But in Europe those licences are limited to vehicles under 7,715 lbs (3500 kg).

Could you tell us whether this driver's licence will be legally sufficient to drive our truck camper of almost 10,000 lbs in the US?

Comment: The states you're planning to visit might be relevant as well. Every state might have different rules.

Comment: I don't know how up-to-date this page is, but probably a good [starting point](http://changingears.com/rv-sec-state-rv-license.shtml).

Comment: I know for a fact that we had no problem renting a rather large RV with such a license but I don't remember the details or know the applicable law so I can't really provide a full answer.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find an official page which addresses the weight of vehicle and foreign licenses, so I head to truck campers renting agencies, and I found the answer there.

From [allmotorhomerentals.com](http://www.allmotorhomerentals.com/USA/):

> **With a normal driving licence you are allowed to drive every recreational vehicle. It doesn't matter if it's a small motorhome or a large buscamper**. The U.S. has an agreement with most countries whereby the renter's full national driving license may be used for a period of up to one year in the U.S.A. International Driving Permits are generally not required in the U.S.A but it is recommended to carry one. If they are taken, they are only valid in conjunction with a full national driving license.

and from [moturis.com](http://www.moturis.com/terms/):

> **DRIVER’S REQUIREMENTS**
>   **Drivers License** A national automobile driver's license is required. We recommend customers
>    to carry a translation of the national driver's license or an international driver's license, but
>    under any circumstances, customer must provide a valid national driver's license at pick-up.
>   **Drivers Age**
>    Minimum age is 21 years for all vehicles

From that I understand that any driver's license is welcomed as long as you are 21 and the license is in English or you carry an international license along with it.

Comment: The USA is too lenient in this area of licensing.  An 85 year old grandma can hop into a 36 foot motorhome and drive off the dealers lot with a regular drivers license and zero training.  But for me to drive a support van on bicycle tours requires a CDL (commerical drivers license) in many states.